# Sonar 4.4 upgrade fails

Tags: upgrade, sonarqube

When trying to upgrade to Sonar 4.4 from 4.3.2, db migration fails with the following

Has anybody seen this before?
Took a quick look in jira issues, but didn't find anything related.

Using MS SQLServer 2008

...
    2014.08.29 11:58:12 INFO  [DbMigration]
    2014.08.29 11:58:12 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  InverseRuleKeyIndex: migrating ============================================
    2014.08.29 11:58:12 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- remove_index(:rules, {:name=>"rules_plugin_key_and_name"})
    2014.08.29 11:58:12 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- Delete duplicated rules
    2014.08.29 11:58:12 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0620s
    2014.08.29 11:58:12 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:rules, [:plugin_name, :plugin_rule_key], {:unique=>true, :name=>"rules_repo_key"})
    2014.08.29 11:58:12 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database
    An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'sonar.rules' and the index name 'rules_repo_key'. The duplicate key value is (grvy, org.codenarc.rule.basic.HardCodedWindowsRootDirectoryRule).: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [rules_repo_key] ON [rules] ([plugin_name], [plugin_rule_key])
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:292:in `add_index'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2235:in `send'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `method_missing'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
    jar:file:/E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:348:in `method_missing'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:124:in `add_index'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/../db/migrate/546_inverse_rule_key_index.rb:66:in `up'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
    jar:file:/E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    E:1:in `migrate'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491:in `migrate'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:565:in `ddl_transaction'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:565:in `ddl_transaction'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in `migrate'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `migrate'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
    E:/Server/sonarqube-4.4/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:109:in `start_migration'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:228:in `call'
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I upgrading from Sonar-3.4 to Sonarqube-4.4, In the testing environment I have  upgraded the database as per the upgrade instructions however its a test server and the DB has no data. Then I restored the DB and restarted sonar (which was a bad approach). So I removed SonarQube, restored Sonar3.4.1 and DB, Restored the latest Sonar DB, Install Sonarqube again and then Upgrade the Sonar DB from the front end using "http://x.x.x.x.:9000/sonar/setup" as mentioned in the Upgrade documentation od SonarQube. It works fine for me without any issues till now.